# Drupal: customize Webform2pdf font-size and line-spacing

Tags: pdf, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

Drupal 7 
Webform 7.x-4.11+23-dev
Webform2pdf 7.x-4.0

My client needs to download/print pdfs of webform submissions.  The form is long so I'd like to compress a 3-page, double-spaced, large-font pdf into 1-2 pages.

What isn't working:

1. Modifying the Webform2pdf configuration (Webform2pdf > Config > Show Content of the PDF document > Page Body > change font-size to 9px)
2. Surrounding [submission:values] or [submission:value:participant_name] inside Page Body, using Full HTML, with inline styles, such as:

   ```
   <p style="font-size: 9px; padding:0;margin:0>[submission:values]</p>
   ```

In fact, the Webform2pdf configuration settings doesn't seem to be controlling the PDF output in any way.

This is a similar issue, as yet unanswered:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560349/drupal-webform2pdf-font-size-of-values/35466647#35466647

Comment: you could try manually changing the settings in the module. It looks like `includes/webform2pdf.settings.inc` line 300 contains information about the pages font size

Comment: Thanks, Ronnie.  I set the default font-size in line 303 of that file to "9" but it's having no effect.  Some other file or module must be controlling the output.